# Extra blank tkinter GUI when executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have to code a game for school. I decided to code it in Pygame but I've decided to create a Settings window in tkinter. The problem is that when I execute my code, it comes in two tkinters: the one that I want, and a blank GUI.

What am I supposed to do to fix this problem ?

Thank you !

```html
import tkinter
import shutil


class Options(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.maxsize(300,200)
        root.minsize(300,200)
        root.title('Difficulté du jeu')

        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        tkinter.Label(root, text= 'Avant de démarrer, merci de selectionner \n une difficulté ou bien fermer la fenêtre pour restaurer \n les paramètres pérécdents. \n \n').pack()
        tkinter.Label(root, text= 'Facile ------------ Classique -------------Débutant').pack()
    
        g_slider_value = 0

        slider = tkinter.Scale(root, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL, length = 300, width = 20, sliderlength = 60, from_ = 45, to = 20, command = self.get_slider)
        slider.pack()
        self.slider = slider
        
        tkinter.Button(root, text='Enregistrer la valeur', command=self.show_values).pack()
        tkinter.Button(root, text='Quitter', command=root.destroy).pack()

    def get_slider(self, event):
     g_slider_value  = self.slider.get()
     print(g_slider_value)


        

    def show_values(self):
        monFichiersource = open('para.txt', 'r')
        monFichiersource.readline() 
        #celà permet de créer le fichier tout d'abord pour ensuite supprimer la première ligne si elle existe
        monFichiercible = open('para.txt', 'w')
        shutil.copyfileobj(monFichiersource, monFichiercible)
        #permet d'écraser les données de l'ancien fichier avec un nouveau vide

        monFichier=open('para.txt','a') #on ouvre le répertoire texte
        monFichier.write(str(self.slider.get())) #on ajoute la valeur du slider
        monFichier.close() #on ferme le fichier
        print('Paramètre enregistré.')

Options().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are combining 2 methods of building a tkinter window into one. There is the non OOP method that does not use a class where you would normally define `Tk()` as root and build using functions and then there is the class method where you would normally inherit from `Tk()` and build your gui using class attributes and methods.

Lets fix you code up.

You never want to call `Tk()` more than once in a tkinter. The reason you are seeing 2 windows is because both your class and inside `__init__` are calling `Tk()`.

You are also not closing 2 of the 3 files you opened so maybe consider using `with open()` instead of `open()` as the `with open()` method will close automatically.

Here is your code cleaned up.

```
import tkinter as tk
import shutil


class Options(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxsize(300, 200)
        self.minsize(300, 200)
        self.title('Difficulté du jeu')
        tk.Label(self, text='Avant de démarrer, merci de selectionner'
                            '\n une difficulté ou bien fermer la fenêtre pour restaurer'
                            '\n les paramètres pérécdents. \n \n').pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Facile ------------ Classique -------------Débutant').pack()
        g_slider_value = 0

        slider = tk.Scale(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, width=20, sliderlength=60, from_=45, to=20,
                               command=self.get_slider)
        slider.pack()
        self.slider = slider

        tk.Button(self, text='Enregistrer la valeur', command=self.show_values).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Quitter', command=self.destroy).pack()

    def get_slider(self, event):
        g_slider_value = self.slider.get()
        print(g_slider_value)

    def show_values(self):
        with open('para.txt', 'r') as monFichiersource:
            monFichiersource.readline()

        with open('para.txt', 'w') as monFichiercible:
            shutil.copyfileobj(monFichiersource, monFichiercible)

        with open('para.txt', 'a') as monFichier:
            monFichier.write(str(self.slider.get()))

        print('Paramètre enregistré.')


Options().mainloop()
```